# Items in javascript array suddenly changed without any reason

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I've been working on a tile-based game, but after playing it for about a minute or so, some tiles just change to a different value. I have found that the code responsible for the sudden change is this part:

```
console.table(field);
console.table(ct);
var xcoord = x;
var ycoord = y;
if(y < 0) {
    redrawField();
    gameOver();
    return;
}
for(var i = 0; i < ct.length; i++) {
    for(var j = 0; j < ct[0].length; j++) {
        if(ct[i][j] == 1) {
            field[ycoord+i][xcoord+j] = index;
        }
    }
}
console.table(field);
```

the `field` variable is a two-dimensional array containing the 'status' of every tile. the `ct` variable has to be copied into the `field` on the x and y coordinates. (The field its vertical so the first index is the y-coordinate (or the row) and the second the x-coordinate (or the column)).

Usually this works fine, so when field is

```
0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

ct is

```
0, 0, 1
1, 1, 1
```

and x and y are 2 and index = 3,
the result is:

```
0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 0, 3
0, 0, 3, 3, 3
```

But sometimes it randomly gives this:

```
0, 0, 0, 0, 3
0, 0, 0, 0, 3
0, 0, 0, 0, 3
0, 0, 3, 3, 3
```

I really can't think of any reason why it would do this, can someone help me?

Thanks in advance.